# How can i extract using regex few values from text to array

Tags: c#, regex

I have text document with this pattern:

Red fox got number1 socks: number2 and: number3

Red fox got number4 socks: number5 and: number6

Red fox got number7 socks: number8 and: number9
...

I need to extract all numberx from each line and put it in array like:

[number1,number2,number3]

[number4,number5,number6]

[number7,number8,number9]

i'm using C#.

thanks

Comment: You want a IEnumerable<int[2]>?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. Why doesn't it work? Show us where and how it fails.  Are you just asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: It can be any type of array which i can loop over.

Comment: @Ben Robinson, i don't know regular expressions at all. What do you suggest me to try ?

Comment: when you write `number1` do you mean the `string` `"number1"` or the `int` `1`?

Comment: @Jodrell, this is text document but number1 is a number like 0 or 1234144

Comment: @eugeneK Try reading up at http://regexlib.com/  There is a good tutorial on regexes as well as a large library of commonly used ones.  You can also test at http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
        var result = input
            .Select(
                line => Regex.Matches(line, @"\d+")
                             .OfType<Match>()
                             .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
            );
        foreach (string[] numbers in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));
        }
    }
}
```

Given the following input file:

```
Red fox got 1 socks: 2 and: 3
Red fox got 4 socks: 5 and: 6
Red fox got 7 socks: 8 and: 9
```

the program prints:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

your regex is:
`"Red fox got ([0-9]+) socks: ([0-9]+) and: ([0-9]+)"`

Comment: Alex how do i distinguish between match1 and match3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regex:

```
string input = "Red fox got 1 socks: 22 and: 333";

string[] split = input.Split(' ');

string output = string.Format("[{0},{1},{2}]", split[3], split[5], split[7]);
```

Put the logic in a loop and for each input add the output to a list or array.

Comment: +1 for creative solution without Regex, never seen it comming.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(theText, "[0-9]+")
{
    var number = int.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

will allow you to iterate all numbers in the text. If you want them in triplets,

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int,int>> NumberTripletsFromText(string theText)
{
    var results = new List<int>;
    var count = 0;

    foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(theText, "[0-9]+")
    {
        count++;
        results.Add(int.Parse(match.Value);

        if (count == 3)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(results[1], results[2], results[3]);
            results.Clear;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    if (results > 0)
    {
       //Handle non divisible by three.
    }
}
```